# Embed iOS App On Web As A Simulation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have created an iOS app. What i want is to embed this app on the web so users can check it inside their desktop browsers first.

what i am trying to achieve is that users can modify it online like design changes and make their own version of it.

For better understanding, let us take an example that the user wants an iPhone app for his website. I can offer a basic template that i have already made using the iOS SDK. User can modify that template on the web, let us say change the name on the navigation bar and change the colour of tool bar etc and then make it as their own version.

The question might be too broad but i just need the direction of how its going to be possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best, perhaps only way to do that would be to develop your app not with the native SDK but instead as a web app. The HTML and JavaScript that drive a web app can of course run in a desktop browser, and it wouldn't be difficult to let the user can be any of the parameters that determine how the app looks or works. The same is not true of native iOS code.

Comment: What i am able to understand from your question is that the project i have made in objective-c using Xcode won't be any help and i have to make a web app using HTML5, CSS and jQuery etc. and then use that web app to be run inside the desktop browsers in order for the users to see it and may be modify it. Right???

Comment: It's either that or create a web-based simulation of your native app. There's no way to display he actual native app self in a browser.

Comment: One tool that may help here is Cappuccino. http://www.cappuccino-project.org It at least would make porting some pieces of the app more mechanical.